# Javascript typeahead after 3 characters

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, bootstrap-typeahead

I want to send a query string to back end after 3 characters, and have the results used for [typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/README.md).

Currently the I get the data back, no error on console, but there is no suggestions in the type ahead. The back end is spring-boot.

It might be something to do with scope of data array but I am not sure.

**CODE:**

```
// doc ready....

$('#queryStation').keyup(function() {
    var stationName = $(this).val();
    if(stationName.length==3){
        ajax_search(stationName);
    }
});

function ajax_search(stationName){
    var stationJson = '{ "name":"' +stationName+ '"}'
    $.ajax ({
       url: "/station",
       type: "POST",
       data: stationJson,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
            $('#queryStation').typeahead({
                source: data
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and html snip:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
   <label class="control-label control-label-left">Station</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="query" id="queryStation" placeholder="Type Station" data-provide="typeahead" autcomplete="off">
</div>
```

The array of objects being sent back in data look like `[ {id:237, name:"LAX"},{id:155,name:"SFO"}....`

It was working when I used $.get instead of ajax POST:

```
    $.get("/station", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("[name='query']").typeahead({
        source: data,
        minLength: 3
    });
}, 'json');
```

The data returned when using $.get looked like `[{"id":1,"name":"LAX","}...` - I see that the key names now are enclosed in " .

**UPDATE**

It appears the problem is to do with the way the data is returned from the server:

```
data =  [{"id":113,"name":"LAX"}]   // Works - $.get
data =  [{id:113,name:"LAX"}]       // Does not work - $.ajax with POST
data = "[{"id":113,"name":"LAX"}]" // Does not work - JSON.stringify result
```

So to get it to work it seems the spring-boot object sent back needs the keys wrapped in quotes. How do do this?

Comment: Please add a portion of your html.

Comment: Your stationJson is not in json format. Create a javascript object and then use JSON.stringify()

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge that wraps the whole array in quotes, ie "[{"id":1,"name":"LAX"

Comment: Try something like: var obj = {"id":113,"name":"LAX"}. And then JSON.stringify(obj)

Comment: The bottom snippets of data, how are you getting those?  Are you getting them from the `console.log()` ?  If you change your console log to `console.log(typeof data)` what does it log for the POST?